# Laravel apply where clause to belongsToMany query using with() method

Tags: laravel, relationship

I have a `products` table with `brand_id`, and a `category_products` table with, `product_id` and `category_id`.

My Products model :

```
class Product extends Model
{
  public function categories() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class)->withTimestamps();
  }
}
```

My Brands Model :

```
class Brand extends Model
{
   public function products() {
     return $this->hasMany(Product::class)->with(['categories']);
   }
}
```

My question is, How can I fetch the products from a `Brand` instance that belongs to certain category?

```
$brand = App\Brand::find(1);

/* 
  I want to be able to do something in the likes of :
*/

 $brand->products_which_are_under_this_category
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `with(['categories'])` method from inside `products()` and write a query like that.

```
$brand->products()->with(['categories' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('category_id', CATEGORY_ID);
}])->get();
```

hope this can help.